Audio interface to Headphone calculations
Audio interfaces and Headphones publish different set of specifications. From these, what kinds of calculations can we do to assess whether the interface is capable of driving the headphone sufficiently (or will it damage the cans when cranked up all the way)?
For instance an audio interface has this spec for headphone jack:
Headphone output at maximum volume: +10 dBu

Suppose it's measured with 1 kHz. I think dBu value is based on 600 ohm impedance load.
A particular brand of headphones has these specs:
Maximum input power: 200 mW
Rated Impedance    : 32 ohm
Sensitivity        : 113 dB SPL/V @ 1 kHz

From these how do I calculate:

What is the maximum power deliverable by the audio interface to this pair headphones?
a. What is the Vrms when audio interface operates at max. (Note +10 dBu is wrt 600 ohm. Does connecting a 32 ohm load change anything at audio interface side?)

What is the SPL when
a. the audio interface is at max level
b. the headphone is getting its max input power (200 mW, from this or any other interface)


I'm interested in knowing relevant formulas and how they can be put together in context for the understanding of flow.
Thanks in advance.

Not sure it can be answered if the intended load impedance is lower than the specced impedance, because it cannot be guaranteed whether the interface will be able to output the same voltage with increased load.

@tobalt I don't think there is any specific intended load impedance in case of audio hardware, except for a known range (e.g. laptop/mobile headphone sockets can work well with upto 32 ohm headphones). I'm curious about how to translate these specs into electrical/math relationships: something like, x dBu = y Vrms with 600 ohm load == z Vrms wrt 32 ohm ==> a mW power, with all necessary equations/formulas.

Below I refer to the interface more broadly as an amplifier as it is an audio amplifier.

The maximum power delivered to the headphone should stay below its rated maximum of 200 mW. The achievable output power will depend on whether your amplifier hits a current limit before it hits its voltage limit. 10 dBu are about 2.45 Vrms. The power at the voltage limit is thus \$P=U^2/R\approx 2.45V^2/32 Ohm\approx 187 mW\$. This is actually below the rated power of your headphones. But I would still be careful with that.

The performance of your amplifier will change when you use a drastically different load (32 Ohm instead of 600 Ohm). With lower impedance the amplifier is more likely to run into a current limit. The distortion and other performance parameters will also measurably change. However a good headphone amplifier should be able to drive both loads at "normal" volumes with good audio quality.


Your sensitivity of SPL @ 1 kHz= 113 dB/V normally refers to the baseline of "how much dB SPL do I get at 1 m distance from my speaker running at 1 W." I will continue my calculation with this assumption below.


The sensitivity (at 1m and 1 W) is \$113 \frac{dB}{W/m}\$. But instead of 1 W we less power. One way to calculate the SPL when the power is changed but the distance stays the same is the following:
$$
SPL=Sensitivity+10*log_{10}(\frac{P}{P_{reference}})
$$
We already have the Sensitivity and the reference power (1 W): $$ SPL=113 \frac{dB}{W/m}+10*log_{10}(\frac{P}{1 W})
$$
Now we only need to enter the power for each scenario:

Maximum power output of your amplifier: We already calculated the power (187 mW). For SPL we take the formula above: \$ SPL=113 \frac{dB}{W/m}+10*log_{10}(\frac{0.187 W}{1 W})\approx 105.7 dB\$
Maximum input power of the headphones: With a 1 kHz sinewave of 200 mW into the headphone you would get: \$ SPL=113 \frac{dB}{W/m}+10*log_{10}(\frac{0.2 W}{1 W})\approx 106 dB\$.

As these are headphones you risk hearing damage when using such audio levels. The SPL at the ears will be much higher then the values shown above. So do not try this while using the headphones on your ears.
These calculations are simplified assumptions.In reality distortion and impedance tolerance or similar can noticeably affect the results.
I recommend to take a look at sengpielaudio.com. It has a lot of explanations and conversions for audio terms and units. E.g. the SPL conversion can be done on a tool on this page: https://sengpielaudio.com/calculator-efficiency.htm (Big Power Formulas)

Agree to remarks 1 and a regarding keeping my ears and headphones safe. I'm more interested in the math aspects of these, especially Voltage and Power calculations (correct approach to do them and the formulas) since there is 600 ohm vs 32 ohm etc. Could you elaborate on these?

285 dBSPL will probably blow you and everything around you to dust ;-). 200mW into 32 Ohms is 2.53V RMS and will increase the pressure level @1kHz by about 8dB to a total of 121dB which is just above the pain threshold.

@Raonoke you are of course correct. I messed up the SPL conversion. Gonna fix that once I find the time.

@AnanthPattabiraman: I corrected my answer. The approach and formulas should give a good example now.

@Raonoke I finally have an SPL below that of a rocket launch. ;)

Loudspeaker sensitivity is usually given at 1W and 1m due to power at the listener's position decreasing in inverse square law with distance. Except for 4 ohms speakers which sometimes use 2.83V instead, corresponding to 1W into 8 ohms, so 2W for 4 ohms, which gives more bigger dB numbers for marketing. But for headphones there is no distance so sensitivity is given as "in your ear dB SPL" directly.

@Grebu - You changed a lot more than neccessary ;-). With headphones there is no measurement distance involved. SPL is already conveniently given in dB/V. 10dBu is equivalent to 2.45V RMS which increases the specified SPL by 7.8dB to a total of 120.8dB. The headphones will not burn up (Pin = 187mW) but the SPL is above the pain threshold (120dB).

This is impossble to calculate.
Your interface output says the value is +10dBu but not the output impedance. Sure it might be +10dBu, but to a assumed 600 ohm load, no load, or assumed line input which may be 10k or higher. As details are missing, it is unknown.
Now, it depends on the output impedance what will be the resulting voltage to your load. You have a voltage divider with one unknown impedance, and your known load.
This might even fall into category of using electrical devices. Don't crank up the volume if you are worried about headphones or decibels reaching to your ears. Or test it into 32 ohm load before trying.
However, assuming zero output impedance, 10dBu is 2.445Vrms, which is only about 188mW into 32 ohms.
If your phones give out 113 dB SPL at 1Vrms, 2.445Vrms is +7.8 dB more than 1 Vrms, so the audio will be about 120 dB SPL.
